# Ionic 3 markers not showing in google map

Tags: angular, google-maps, ionic-framework

I need to show the markers on map . i get the code from somewhere map is loading fine but there is error show in console InvalidValueError: setMap: not an instance of Map; and not an instance of StreetViewPanorama . any one can help how i can solve this Thanks

```
  import { Component } from '@angular/core';
  import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

  import { ViewChild } from '@angular/core'


  import { GoogleMaps } from '@ionic-native/google-maps';

  declare var google;

 @Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
  export class HomePage {

@ViewChild('map') mapElement: ElementRef;
private map: any;


 constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private googleMaps: GoogleMaps) 
{} 


loadMap() {
let latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(24.926295, 67.130499);

let mapOptions = {
 center: latLng,
 zoom: 15,
 mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
   }

this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.mapElement.nativeElement, mapOptions);    

 var locations = [
  ['Darul-sehat Hospital', 24.861624, 67.006629],
  ['Memon Hospital ', 24.9456, 67.146],

];

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

var marker, i;

for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
  map: map
 });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
   return function() {
   infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
   infowindow.open(map, marker);
   }
  })(marker, i));
}
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are not using proper google map reference. Try the below code that works for me.

```
marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
  map: this.map
});
```

The only thing you want to change is `map: map` to `map: this.map` in the above function.

Comment: If the solution is works for you then please accept answer.